# How to use manage checkbox to collect the result?

Tags: android, checkbox

I have made a page where there are several questions and each question has four options to be selected by a user only one at a time. At the bottom of the page there is submit button which checks all the answers that are checked in checkbox. How can I manage this please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a radio group for each question having answer options as radio button. And the submit button code should check whether all questions have been answered by checking whether any one of radio button particular to a question is clicked(checked) or not.

Comment: could you please elaborate, what should i have to do in submit button. And how can I manage using arrays.